# I just want a simple load data (div) on scroll function

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, scroll

I've been looking around for a simple load data on scroll before the bottom of page.

I'm looking for one just like what revolt dot tv have implemented on their home page.

I found one http://jsfiddle.net/YM5dp/270/

```
 function loadMore()
{
   console.log("More loaded");
    $("body").append(".div");
   $(window).bind('scroll', bindScroll);
 }

 function bindScroll(){
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100) {
       $(window).unbind('scroll');
       loadMore();
   }
}

$(window).scroll(bindScroll);
```

but I cant seem to implement it on my site 
i'am not sure why my div isn't being triggered.

My homepage continuous to load all divs at once. http://img.studio-heads.net/

Comment: What you're looking for is called "infinite scroll." Have a look here http://www.jquery4u.com/tutorials/jquery-infinite-scrolling-demos/ or check google.

Comment: A side note, read about cons and pros about infinite scroll here https://econsultancy.com/blog/61703-infinite-scrolling-pros-and-cons and here http://designmodo.com/infinite-scrolling/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(window).scroll(function () { 
   if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 10) {
      //Add something at the end of the page
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw you page. I guess you are calling a jquery function before the jquery library is being loaded. Please add the jquery library before the script call.

```
  Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

Means that $ isnt initialized and hence jquery is not loaded.

Comment: @user3618908 Any luck with it ?

Comment: no luck but i recently found a jquery that creates pagination. http://www.script-tutorials.com/how-to-create-easy-pagination-with-jquery/I'm just looking for a way it can work by being triggered on scroll